# Getting "development" errors in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger, production-environment

I'm having a strange problem: I'm running my server in production mode, everything is fine, but I keep getting error messages like they appear in development mode. So for example instead of a 404 page, I'm getting "No route matches "/foo" with {:method=>:get}". Also "exception notifier" stopped sending exceptions.

I put <%= "Environment: #{RAILS_ENV}" %> into a view, to double-check I am definitly in production mode, which is true. Never had this before.

I'm on rails 2.3.8 on a shared server, running passenger.

Thanks for any help,

Ron

Comment: Check the production environment's config file, and the main `environment.rb` config file.

Comment: I checked there before... in production.rb: "config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false". In the environment.rb there is nothing unusual. What is it I should look out for?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like this one:
http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=109

The general recommendation is to remove the config.ru from the root of your app. It seems to confuse Passenger quite a bit.

Comment: Don't remove config.ru. It's only meant to be a workaround for the 2.2 series which didn't support smart spawning for Rack apps. Removing config.ru forced it to recognize Rails 3 apps as Rails apps instead of as Rack apps. Phusion Passenger 3.0 supports smart spawning for all Rack apps so you shouldn't remove config.ru anymore; upgrade to Phusion Passenger 3!

Answer (score 0):

upgrading your Phusion Passenger seems to be the solution.